# Can a faulty MacBook be replaced for a brand new one?

Tags: macbook-pro, repair, services, magic-trackpad

7 months I ago I bought a new MacBook air 2019. Just recently the trackpad of my MacBook stopped clicking. As in, the haptic feedback from the clicking randomly stoped working. I sent my laptop over to an Apple authorized service provider since my country doesn't have an apple store, for a diagnosis. After the diagnosis they called me up and said that I have a hardware issue and they need to order certain parts internationally to properly fix the haptic system failure. However, ordering the parts and then fixing it is going to take a very long time, and time isn't what I simply have as I would be traveling the next month. So, I was wondering if it's possible instead of the repair and since I am within the warranty if I can get my entire laptop replaced for a new one? I hope someone can provide some response.

Comment: *I hope someone can provide some response.* The only entity that can provide an authoritative response is one which is contractually obliged to replace faulty goods, and one which admits that your rather new MacBook is faulty.  The warranty you mention may be that contractual obligation but (a) it may give the other party (ie whoever issued the warranty) the right to offer a repair rather than a replacement (b) you may need to convince them that the MacBook was faulty and that the problem is not a result of, say, your own carelessness.

Comment: Further, you may have bought the MacBook in a jurisdiction within which laws and other regulations concerning the supply of goods apply and which give you rights beyond the terms of the warranty's text.  Those can be very helpful, but it's not unknown for suppliers to snap their fingers at such regulations and cry *Prove it* or some such.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark so u are saying that regardless there is a possibility for the authorised reseller to replace my laptop

Comment: No, I'm saying, read your warranty and discuss the situation with whoever issued it - which may be the authorised reseller but may be a third party.